# How do I override setter in subclass without causing StackOverflowError?

Tags: grails, groovy

I defined a class similar to the following:

```
class Person {

  String name
  ...

}
```

When I try to override the setter for `name`, as shown below, I get `StackOverflowError`.

```
class SuperHero extends Person {

  void setName(String name) {
    this.name = deriveSuperHeroName(name)
  }

}
```

It seems like assignment using `this.name` delegates to `setName` which causes the problem, but I can't think of a way to work around it...

Comment: Or `this.@name = ...` should work too

Comment: @tim_yates but '@name' isn't an equivalent of 'getName()'?

Comment: No, it's a direct property access

Comment: @tim_yates actually that's the kind of solution I was looking for. I was searching if there were other built-in references like `self` or something. Thanks!

Comment: @tim_yates it doesn't seem to work if the property is declared with default modifier, though. Only works with `public`, or `protected`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should work fine:

```
class Person 
{
    String name
}

class SuperHero extends Person 
{
    @Override
    void setName(String name) 
    {
        super.setName(deriveSuperHeroName(name))
    }

    def deriveSuperHeroName(name)
    {
        name
    }
}
```

Or also without @Override annotation:

```
class SuperHero extends Person 
{
    void setName(String name) 
    {
        super.setName(deriveSuperHeroName(name))
    }

    def deriveSuperHeroName(name)
    {
        name
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried referencing via `super` before I asked the question here, but I think I missed the part that it worked. I tried it again and now I can see it works. The `@Override` annotation is optional, I think. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's optional without @Override annotation it's also compile :)